# Silverlight wcf ria services : Validation Annotation questions

Tags: silverlight, wcf, validation, service, ria

How do i do the equivalent of `[Required]` in xaml code behind?

I have a dataform that autogenerates the fields from a domain service class. Is it possible to add or remove the `[Required]` validation in the `_AutoGeneratingField` method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to create extension class for your entity, where you can use `[Required]` attribute.

If you need some examples - let me know.

Comment: I have read about extensions, a quick ex would be save me a lot of time

Comment: Please, give little more information about problem. Code sample will help us to solve issue in a correct way.